# Error while synch db in Django 1.4

Tags: django-1.4

I just started using Django 1.4 and am facing an issue while executing running syncdb.

1. Executed the following:

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode$ django-admin.py startproject  mysite

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode$ ls mysite

   manage.py  mysite
   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode$ cd mysite/

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite$ ls

   manage.py  mysite

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite$ cd mysite/

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite/mysite$ ls

   **init**.py  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite/mysite

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite$ python manage.py  startapp blog

   mynane@mynane:~/djsamplecode/mysite$ ls blog/

   **init**.py  models.py  tests.py  views.py

As per django 1.4 documentaion this is expected:

Added the name of my appplication 'blog' the settings.py as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mysite.blog',
```

Modified the mysite/blog/models.py and executed

python manage.py syncdb and got the following error:

```
myname@myname:~/djsamplecode/mysite/blog$ python ../manage.py  syncdb
Error: No module named blog
```

If i modify settings.py as

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'blog'
```

it is working fine. Can someme help me understand the directory structure in Django1.4?

Answer (score 0):

Your apps can be placed anywhere within `PYTHONPATH` and then you can add appnamame eg `blog` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also it is not a bad idea to place your apps outside the project directory (within `PYTHONPATH`) in order to make them more reusable.